# Dynamically Enable/Disable a DropDownList based on CheckBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, dropdown

I've got the following in a partial view, representing a row that is added dynamically:

```
<td>
    <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />   
</td>
<td>
    <input asp-for="EnableDropDown1" id="EnableDropDown1Id" type="checkbox" class="form-control" />
</td>
<td>
    <select asp-for="MyDropDown1" id="MyDropDownId1" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<MyEnum1Type>()" disable="disabled" class="form-control"></select>
</td>
<td>
    <input asp-for="EnableDropDown2" id="EnableDropDown2Id" type="checkbox" class="form-control" />
</td>
<td>
    <select asp-for="MyDropDown2" id="MyDropDownId2" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<MyEnum2Type>()" disable="disabled" class="form-control"></select>
</td>
```

I thought that maybe an onclick="EnableDropDown()" call attached to the CheckBox (that took a checkbox and a dropdown parameter) might do the trick, but it doesn't keep the state nor does the checkbox find the appropriate dropdown. I could loop through all the rows on a click and enable/disable dropdowns appropriately but this seems like a poor solution.

I've seen a fair few solutions out there but none of the simple ones work... either because they're not dynamic, or maybe it's down to the multiple checkboxes, or the fact it's an EnumSelectList and not a simple DropDown (Is there a difference?)..

I'm not too well-versed on javascript so I'm a bit lost with this one.

Comment: Why can't you do your onclick solution? If you have the checkbox id and dropdown id, you can get HTML elements through jQuery/DOM, get checkbox state and do the job. If you don't want to get the checkbox state on every change, just get it at start and store it in a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are missing a "d" in the disabled attribute

Then if you are adding the row dynamically that means that the events are not added when the dom load, you can modify this behavior using a parent selector that already exists when the dom is rendered, also add some references using data-attributes between inputs and select make easier handle this

Try using the following code

```js
$(".parent-class").on("change",".checkbox-class", function() {
  var enabledDropdown = $(this).data("dropdown")
  $(`#${enabledDropdown}`).removeAttr("disabled")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="parent-class">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />   
</td>
<td>
    <input data-dropdown="MyDropDownId1" asp-for="EnableDropDown1" id="EnableDropDown1Id" type="checkbox" class="form-control checkbox-class" />
</td>
<td>
    <select asp-for="MyDropDown1" id="MyDropDownId1" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<MyEnum1Type>()" disabled="disabled" class="form-control"></select>
</td>
<td>
    <input data-dropdown="MyDropDownId2" asp-for="EnableDropDown2" id="EnableDropDown2Id" type="checkbox" class="form-control checkbox-class" />
</td>
<td>
    <select asp-for="MyDropDown2" id="MyDropDownId2" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<MyEnum2Type>()" disabled="disabled" class="form-control"></select>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This code does not take into account the navigators keeping the state of the checkbox on page reload. Secondly, it does not disable the dropdown again when unchecking the checkbox.